# How to protect multiple connected accounts from one compromised account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

If you connect two accounts with AWS DirectConnect, how can you prevent that if a service in one account has been compromised, the attacker also gains access to the second AWS account?

Is there only the possibility of recognizing unexpected behavior?

In my opinion, this problem is increased by using AWS TransitGateway - by connecting many AWS accounts with each other? Is this a common practice?

I hope the question is not too general. Maybe one of you can give me a few key points that will give me a better understanding of how to secure such a connection against attacks from one AWS account to another AWS account (both connected with AWS DirectConnect)

Comment: I think this all depends on what level of access you grant cross account role/s that are used. The TGW does only give the possibility to route traffic between accounts.

Comment: Does that mean that AWS DirectConnect does not give one account any permissions in the other account? This is only then regulated via IAM.

Comment: Which AWS services help me to recognize that the account has been compromised despite being least privileged with IAM?

Comment: AWS Direct Connect is a fiber connection between on-premises networks and AWS. It does not "connect multiple accounts". You might want to read-up on what the AWS Direct Connect service provides.

Comment: AWS has a series of security tools. For monitoring api calls you have Cloudtrail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right to be concerned about the security implications of connecting multiple AWS accounts, especially when using services like AWS Direct Connect and AWS Transit Gateway.

While DirectConnect on its own will not cause the traffic to leak between your accounts / VPCs, the on-premises network equipment might hairpin the traffic between them if routing is configured in an insecure way.

On TGW side you need to ensure that your propagation / association policies are configured to segment the network properly and prevent the traffic from "leaking" to the accounts where it shouldn't end up.

If all of this looks too complicated you can look at overlay solutions that simplify cloud networking and let traditional on-prem network engineers use their existing super-powers in the cloud networks. One such solution is Aviatrix. (DISCLAIMER: I am part of Aviatrix, but only because it's awesome!).

In addition to the points above you may want to consider the following:

Here are some key points to consider in order to secure connections between AWS accounts:

1. Use AWS Organizations: This service enables you to centrally manage and enforce policies across multiple AWS accounts. By using AWS Organizations, you can implement service control policies (SCPs) to restrict the actions users or roles can take in your accounts, which helps limit the blast radius in case an account gets compromised.
2. Implement the principle of least privilege: Limit the permissions granted to users, roles, and resources in each AWS account. Assign only the minimum required permissions to perform specific tasks. This will help to minimize the potential damage if an attacker gains access to one of your AWS accounts.
3. Use IAM roles for cross-account access: If resources in one account need to access resources in another account, use IAM roles with the necessary permissions instead of using shared access keys. Roles provide temporary credentials and can be assumed by trusted entities, reducing the risk of long-lived keys being compromised.
4. Enable AWS CloudTrail and Amazon GuardDuty: CloudTrail logs API activity in your accounts, while GuardDuty is a managed threat detection service that can monitor for unusual behavior or unauthorized access. These services can help you detect and respond to security incidents quickly.
5. Use AWS PrivateLink: AWS PrivateLink allows you to securely access services in another VPC (in the same or different account) over a private connection, without exposing your traffic to the public internet. This reduces the attack surface and can help prevent unauthorized access to your services.
6. Implement other network segmentation features: Using VPCs, subnet isolation, and security groups, you can limit the scope of connectivity between resources in different AWS accounts. Ensure that only required resources can communicate with each other, reducing the potential impact of an attack.
7. Encrypt data in transit and at rest: Use encryption to protect sensitive data as it moves between AWS accounts and while it's stored. This can help prevent unauthorized access to your data, even if an attacker gains access to one of your AWS accounts.