# Networking final year project suggestions

Tags: security, networking, network-programming, network-security

I want some suggestions about a networking project for my final year in network engineering like something related to secure app within a network I want to know what should I do other than firewall or DMZ

---

Answer (score 0):

With the world moving into the Cloud, Cloud networking is the next big thing.

I suggest getting a free tier in AWS and Azure (all you need is a credit card). And trying to build a multi-cloud network.

For bonus points, you can build a shiny overlay between the two and show all the NetFlow traffic that is being collected.

This can be a great starting point:
https://community.aviatrix.com/t/g9hx9jh/aviatrix-cloud-sandbox-starter-spin-up-cloud-networks-in-minutes

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Keep in mind that, while you did disclose your affiliation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75927181/11810933), you need to do that *every* time you link to your company in a post - *["... if you mention your product, website, etc. in your question or answer (or any other contribution to the site), you must disclose your affiliation in your post."](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).

Comment: Also keep in mind the [GPT ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) here, which includes Bing and other AI tools.  I could be wrong, but some of your answers look like they may have some GPT content in them.  However, that could simply be your natural writing style; I know mine could easily be confused for AI in some cases as well.

Comment: I appreciate the reminder, @NotTheDr01ds. I will always disclose my affiliation despite it being stated in my profile. And yes, I'm unfamiliar with how GPT detection technology works, but it's an interesting theme for further exploration. I'm sure writing in a humanized way will soon become a skill people will start including in resumes.